# Python. imap_tools. Cant use search criteria

Tags: python, imap, imap-tools

Why did this script didn't work?
I've tested on gmail.com, IMAP, mail.ru, yandex.ru IMAPs.

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND, A

mb = MailBox('imap.gmail.com').login('email', 'password')
messages = mb.fetch(criteria=A(AND(seen=False), AND(date=current_date)),
                    mark_seen=False,
                    bulk=False)
for msg in messages:
    print(msg)
```

Out:
imap_tools.errors.MailboxSearchError: Response status "OK" expected, but "NO" received. Data: [b'[CANNOT] Unsupported search criterion: (UNSEEN) ON 27-JUL-2021']

Thx!

Comment: Try simplifying the AND structure. A(A(x), A(y)) is the same as just A(x, y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simpler: A(seen=False, date=current_date)

if same error: means that your server can not do it

Code below works on my gmail acc:

```
for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(seen=True, date=datetime.date(2020, 4, 22))):
    print(msg.date, msg.from_)
```

Comment: Same error. How to fetch emails from today which I haven't seen?

Comment: @SviatoslavS , "Unsupported search criterion" means that your server can not do it.